# Safari добавляет иконку в input

Tags: html, css, html5, веб-программирование, safari

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.

*Safari (версия 10.0.1)* по своему кастомизирует обычный `input type="text"`.
`input` блокируется, невозможно ввести значение. Кто нибудь может сталкивался?

```html
<label> 
  <span>Подъезд</span>
  <input type="text" name="home_custom_adres[]" value="" class="input">
</label>
```

[image]

Comment: А можно пример кода?

Comment: <label>
                                            <span>Подъезд</span>
                                            <input type="text" name="home_custom_adres[]" value="" class="input">
                                        </label>

Comment: Скорее всего, это работа некого расширения браузера. Квк первый input  (адрес) отображается в консоли?